# Get ordered data from precedence relationship of 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

In the scenario I have to get the data in the right order based on the precedence structure of the rows. Let the table data be:

Table (Desc - A part of B)

```
col1 col2 col3
a    1    11 
a    1    12
a    1    13
b    2    21 
b    2    22
b    2    23
```

Table (Desc - Sequence)

```
col1 col2 col3
aa   11    12 
bb   13    14
cc   12    13
pp   21    22 
qq   23    24
rr   22    23
```

The result I am expecting:

```
col1 col2
a     aa
a     cc
a     bb
b     pp
b     rr
b     qq
```

I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `JOIN` with ORDER BY `T1.col` then `T2.col2`

```
SELECT T1.col1,
       T2.col1
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 
ON T1.col3 = T2.col2
ORDER BY T1.col1,
       T2.col2
```